# Fetch Inside A Fetch - Objects Are Not Valid As A React Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to make two fetch requests. The second one cannot be completed until MemberId is retrieved from the first one. I have tried putting them in separate async functions but keep getting the below error.

Any insights on the best way to do this would be much appreciated.

Error message:
*Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default async function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isLoadingMp, setLoadingMp] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [mpData, setMpData] = useState([]);
  let memberId = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://members-api.parliament.uk/api/Members/Search?Name=Boris%20Johnson`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setMpData(json);
        memberId = json.items[0].value.id;
        console.log("memberId:", memberId);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .then(
        fetch(
          `https://commonsvotes-api.parliament.uk/data/divisions.json/membervoting?memberId=${memberId}`
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => setData(json))
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
          .finally(() => setLoading(false))
          .finally(() => {
            setLoadingMp(false);
          })
      );
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading || isLoadingMp ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: `${mpData.items[0].value.thumbnailUrl}`,
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              }}
            />
            <Text>{`${mpData.items[0].value.id}\n`}</Text>

            {data.map((individualData) => {
              return `\nDate: ${
                individualData.PublishedDivision.Date
              }\nDivision id: ${
                individualData.PublishedDivision.Date
              }\nDivision title: ${
                individualData.PublishedDivision.Title
              }\nVoted: ${!!individualData.MemberVotedAye ? "Yes" : "No"}\n`;
            })}
          </Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: one issue is that `.then` expects a function as an argument, where as you're calling fetch directly, and therefore `memberId` would not yet be set since the "inner" fetch is called too soon ... quick fix `.then(() => fetch( .... etc`

Comment: This error usually comes when the view element tries to show an object, as the view should always contain values and not objects.

I've given an answer below as to how you can simplify the API call one step further.

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be with fetches, but rather with rendering. Since I don't know the exact structure of the data, it'll be difficult to figure out what exactly is going wrong. But if I were to guess, the issue might be with dates, i.e. if they are date objects, then convert them to string using .toString methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isLoadingMp, setLoadingMp] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [mpData, setMpData] = useState([]);
  let memberId = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi = async ()=>{//defining a async function to call the API
      
      setLoading(true);//maybe you just need one loading flag
      try{

      const result = await (await fetch(
      `https://members-api.parliament.uk/api/Members/Search?Name=Boris%20Johnson`
      )).json();//first api and json() its result
      const memberId = result.items[0].value.id;//get the member id from it
      
      const finalResult = await(await fetch(
          `https://commonsvotes-api.parliament.uk/data/divisions.json/membervoting?memberId=${memberId}`
        )).json();//second api call and json() its result
        //set the state
        setData(finalResult);
        setMpData(result);
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
      }finally{
          setLoading(false);//set loading false in both the fail and success case
      }
    }
    callApi();//calling the function
  }, []);

 //VIEW rendering
  return (<View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: `${mpData.items[0].value.thumbnailUrl}`,
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              }}
            />
            <Text>{`${mpData.items[0].value.id}\n`}</Text>

            {data.map((individualData) => {
              return `\nDate: ${
                individualData.PublishedDivision.Date
              }\nDivision id: ${
                individualData.PublishedDivision.Date
              }\nDivision title: ${
                individualData.PublishedDivision.Title
              }\nVoted:  ? "Yes" : "No"}\n`;
            })}
          </Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This specific problem has nothing to do with the `fetch`es, it is simpler.

You declared your functional component as `async`:

```
export default async function App() {
```

The consequence is that it doesn't return a React element but a Promise that resolves to a React element, which React can't handle.

Remove the `async`:

```
export default function App() {
```